# Adding a bundle to a Fragment from a FragmentActivity

Tags: android

I have the following lines in my code

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, fargmentTag);
```

Now I want to add a bundle to my fragment. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

Anywhere inside your FragmentActivity class, put this:

```
MyFragmentClass mFrag = new MyFragmentClass();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("DocNum", docNum);   //parameters are (key, value).
mFrag.setArguments(bundle);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.page_fragments, mFrag).commit();
```

I’m using “import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;” so I use “getSupportFragmentManager()”. 
So to summarize the code above, u created a bundle instance and an instance of your fragment. Then you associated the two objects with “mFrag.setArguments(bundle)”. So now the “bundle” is associated with that instance of your MyFragmentClass. So anywhere in your MyFragmentClass, retrieve the bundle by calling:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String mDocNum = bundle.getString("DocNum");
```

Answer (score 5):

Before `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, fargmentTag);` add the following line:

`fragment.setArguments(bundle)`.

Comment: how do i recieve them on the other end

Comment: @user1730789: getArguments() will retrieve the bundle you set above.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `replace` just add `fragment.setArguments(bundle)`